# Rokoko retargeting animation displaces bezier curve

Tags: animation, armature, bezier-curves, mixamo

I have a bezier curve (at the back of the neck) that reacts correctly when I pose the character manually. When i retarget an animation from Mixamo using Rokoko, everything works fine except the bezier curve. It jumps to another location weirdly, seen in image 2. I have tried to apply transform to the bezier curve, but that also makes it change position.

How can I make the curve follow the mesh/armature normally when retargeting with Rokoko?

[image]

[image]

[image]